# Visual studio C++ connect to MYSQL server

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, mysql-connector

I got errors when T try to run my c++ program to connect to MYSQL server. Here is my code.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" 
 #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" 
 #include <cmath> 
 #include <iostream> 
 #include "my_global.h" 
 #include "mysql.h"

 int main() {MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
char *server = "server";
char *user = "user";
char *password = "password";  // got tot keep my data secret
char *database = "cpp_test";
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

// connect to database
if(!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    return -1;
}

// send SQL query
if(mysql_query(conn, "select * from cpp_testTAB"))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    return -1;
}

res = mysql_use_result(conn);

// output table name
printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]);
}

// close connection
mysql_free_result(res);
mysql_close(conn);
return 0;
}
```

Here is my additional include directories

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include
```

Additional Library Directories

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\lib\opt
```

Additional Dependencies

```
libmysql.lib
mysqlcppconn-static.lib
```

There are the errors that i got when I try  to run the program.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_close referenced in function main   
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_free_result referenced in function main 
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_row referenced in function main   
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_use_result referenced in function main  
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_query referenced in function main   
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_error referenced in function main   
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_connect referenced in function main
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_init referenced in function main

Error   9   error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Lahiru\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Level4-Project\x64\Debug\Level4-Project.exe
```

I am unable to solve this problem. if anyone can show me error or sample tutorial link that will be great.

Comment: Look at the last error.  It has `x64` in the path, while you have `Program Files (x86)` in the other errors.  Looks like you've mixed up 32-bit and 64-bit build.

Comment: I commented mysql connection code and other code will work for `x64` and i have installed all the mysql libraries for `x64`. but I think what you're saying is right. how can I fix this ? I have x64 machaine

Comment: If it is a 64-bit app you're compiling then the libraries must be 64-bit.  Again, your paths for those libraries are highly suspicious to me, since they were placed in the directory that 32-bit apps use.

Comment: you're right. please add this as answer. I'll accept it

Comment: ok.  Answer was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're building a 64-bit application, but supplying 32-bit libraries.  What gives this impression are these two lines:

```
Error   9   error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals   
C:\Users\Lahiru\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Level4-Project\x64\Debug\Level4-Project.exe
```

and this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib
```

The first line has `x64` in the path, but the second line suggests that the libraries you're looking for are 32-bit versions due to the `Program Files (x86)` path.

Therefore make sure you're linking in 64-bit libraries with your 64-bit application, or change your app to 32-bit and link with the 32-bit libraries.